# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Was not expecting to find existing database transaction

Tags: corda

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Was not expecting to find existing database transaction on current strand when setting database: Thread[Test worker,5,main], net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.DatabaseTransaction@3e9f2c2e
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.<init>(CordaPersistence.kt:79)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNodeKt.configureDatabase(AbstractNode.kt:900)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:668)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(InternalMockNetwork.kt:315)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:208)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.start(InternalMockNetwork.kt:245)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNodeImpl(InternalMockNetwork.kt:377)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:363)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:358)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNotaries$node_driver(InternalMockNetwork.kt:211)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:194)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:100)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:217)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:211)
    at com.synechron.cordapp.flows.FlowUnitTests.setup(FlowUnitTests.kt:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have test class to for testing Corda custom flow, individual test cases are running successfully, but throwing above exception when I run the class itself. A flow only has code to create the `linear state` and consumes existing state if already exists on `vault` than distribute to participants. No extraordinary logic or `DB session` opening.

The test classes are written for other flows of the same project working without any exception. 
Don't know why it is leaking the `DB tx` in between the `test cases` execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `MockNode`s, you should explicitly open a database transaction for a specific node before performing an operation that accesses its database:

```
mockNodeA.transaction {
    // Access to the node's database...
}
```

You can see an example here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/com/example/flow/IOUFlowTests.kt#L110

If you fail to do so:

- You may accidentally access the database of the wrong node
- You will get an `IllegalStateException` when you create a new `MockNetwork` in the next suite of tests if you're running several test suites in a row